# Spring Security - Custom authentication without provider?

Tags: spring-security

I have a hybrid application that uses Spring Security for roles validation but not for login.
PreAuthorize fails with "An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext"

I tried to add this to my Login controller but it doesn't seem to work:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(makeAuthentication(op));
```

The configuration is as follow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {}
```

Am I forced to use an authentication provider? How would it work in this case? The user roles are stored in the Operator object.

EDIT: It looks like the SecurityContext gets cleared between requests. How do I make it persistent?
I tried adding the security context to the session as `SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY` attribute but still no luck.
In the end, I made it work by restoring the context in an interceptor. Not sure this is the best way though.

Comment: Can you add your spring security config? Spring security by default persists your SecurityContext in session. Are your subsequent requests sending `JSESSIONID` cookie?

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai I am using spring security config.

Comment: I was trying to understand if you client is making the subsequent requests on the same session. If it is the case, can you add your spring security config and also the url you use to custom login

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your client is sending subsequent requests on the same session as your custom login request
2. If that is ensured, check if your custom login url goes through spring security but as an unsecured url. If it is not the case, you have to add the following to your custom login success stage.

```
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(makeAuthentication(op));
    HttpSession session = req.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute(SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT_KEY, 
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext());
```

3. Once these steps are in place, Spring security's `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` will ensure `SecurityContextHolder.getContext()` is populated on subsequent requests.